# Could a Titan Mauler Titan Fighter use a Large Greatsword in one hand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, fighter, barbarian

Can a multiclass [Titan Mauler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/titan-mauler) 3 and [Titan Fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/titan-fighter) 1 wield a **LARGE** Greatsword in one hand? If so, how would the attack be calculated?

STR 20+5, BAB +4, Masterwork Large Greatsword.

+5(STR)+4(BAB)+1(Masterwork)-4(Massive Weapons)-2(Giant Weapon Wielder) = +4

Is that **correct** and **possible**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Although the character's trying *really* hard, he still can't wield a too-big two-handed weapon in one hand

What stops the Medium [titan mauler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/titan-mauler) [barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian) 3/[titan fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/titan-fighter) [fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter) 1 from wielding in one hand a Large two-handed weapon—despite his many special abilities allowing him to wield weapons of unusual sizes—is the restriction on the extraordinary ability jotungrip of the archetype [titan mauler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/titan-mauler), which says

> At 2nd level, a titan mauler may choose to wield a two-handed melee weapon in one hand with a –2 penalty on attack rolls while doing so. **The weapon must be appropriately sized** for her, and it is treated as one-handed when determining the effect of Power Attack, Strength bonus to damage, and the like.

Emphasis mine. The [titan mauler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/titan-mauler) archetype's extraordinary ability massive weapons allows the warrior to use 2-handed weapons that are *inappropriately* sized more easily, and so does the [titan fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/titan-fighter) archetype's extraordinary ability giant weapon wielder, but neither special ability *changes* how the special ability jotungrip functions, and that special ability functions only on appropriately sized weapons, and that's the one that would need to change for the character to use in one hand a two-handed too-big weapon.

Comment: But there is also the [Massive Weapons] from Titan Mauler 3rd level.

At 3rd level, a titan mauler becomes skilled in the use of massive weapons looted from her titanic foes.

She can use two-handed weapons meant for creatures one size category larger, but the penalty for doing so is increased by 4. However, the attack roll penalty for using weapons too large for her size is reduced by 1, and this reduction increases by 1 for every three levels beyond 3rd (to a minimum of 0).

This ability replaces trap sense.

Comment: If there was a feat that said the character could now consider weapons 1 size larger than normal as "appropriately sized", I'd say that would allow it to be used with Jotungrip. But none of the feats say that, and the fact that there is still mention of a penalty (and thus the weapon must not really be appropriately sized) further supports this interpretation. +1

Comment: @Zarkos I mentioned the special ability massive weapons in my answer. Being able to use two-handed weapons meant for a creature one size category larger doesn't change them to one-handed nor does it make the inappropriately big weapon appropriately sized. The special ability massive weapons just *can't* change jotungrip. (I'm not trying wet-blanket. I wish it did, too, but it seems jotungrip is written ruthlessly to prevent exactly what's being attempted.)